# Thread doesn't stop fast enough

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, slider

Hi and sorry for my poor english,

In my WPF application I have a RepeatButton which increment a slider value.

Each time the slider value change, I have to stop a thread wich is generating pictures and run the same again depending the new slider value :

```
  Console.WriteLine("Request stop !");
                requestStop();
                Console.WriteLine(bw.IsAlive.ToString());

                valuetogenerate = searchValueToGenerate();

                bw = new Thread(() => bw_DoWork());
                requestStart();
                bw.Start();
```

Declaration

```
 private volatile bool _shouldStop;
```

My requestStop and start method :

```
  public void requestStop()
    {
        _shouldStop = true;
    }

    public void requestStart()
    {
        _shouldStop = false;
    }
```

And the DoWork :

```
 while (!_shouldStop && !(allvaluegenerated))
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < valuetogenerate.Count - 1; i++)
            {

             Console.WriteLine("i :" + i + " " + System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());

                if (!_shouldStop)
                {

                      .... generating pictures     

                }
                else
                {
                     i = valuetogenerate.Count + 1;
                }
            }
        }

 Console.WriteLine("Thread stopped");
```

Issue is the thread doesn't stop fast enough (I think ...), that's my output window with thread id after i value :

```
 Number of value to generate : 6
 Begin generation : 
 i :0 15
 i :1 22
 i :1 23
 i :2 21
 i :2 20
 i :1 19
 i :1 15
 i :2 22
 i :2 23
 i :2 19
 i :3 20
 i :3 21
 i :2 15
 i :3 19
 i :3 22
 i :3 23
 i :4 20
 i :4 21
 i :3 15
 i :4 22
 i :4 19
 Thread stopped
 i :4 23
 Thread stopped
 i :4 15
 Thread stopped
 Thread stopped
 Thread stopped
 Thread stopped
```

As you can see thread are not stopped when I ask to be stopped.

Using thread.abort after requestStop solved my issue but it's not the most elegant way to stop thread.

Comment: you want to stop the thread only to update UI??

Comment: No, the thread allow me to put picture in hashatable and the hashtable is used in my main thread. Every time I stop and run the thread I update the hashtable with new pictures (cache system). The pictures are displayed in a Image component

Comment: Please excuse me if I have misunderstood, but if this is related to a UI operation, why did you chose to use a Thread rather than a Delegate and a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to launch it? Rather than a thread.abort, you could try a Join, but this will potentially still not end the thread expediently.

Comment: When application run first time the thread generate 100 pictures, after that, each time the slider change value I take the first picture in the hashtable to display it and I run the thread to generate the 101st picture (the first picture is removed from hashtable). Taking the picture to displayed it cost less time than generate the picture and displayed it. I use thread because I don't want my application to freeze each time the slider change value. (The goal of app is to display graph and move in the graph, the graph can be more than 24h)

Answer (score 3):

You should only request that a thread be cancelled and let the thread handle that cancellation process itself. If that means it takes a while for the thread to do so then so be it. Aborting threads should only be done as a last resort.

But anyway... Why don't you break the loop when _shouldStop == true?

```
if (!_shouldStop)
{
  .... generating pictures     
}
else
{
   break;
}
```

Ah, I see... you are setting the value of i so that the loop condition changes

Comment: Most important, the thread seems to run an endless loop without ever pausing.

Comment: Yes the while loop condition needs attention

Answer (score 1):

If you need to interact (like stopping/starting) in an asynchronous situation (like two threads) there will always be delays. So you cannot expect to issue the command "stop" and expect it will be stopped immediately.

Think of two persons communicating by email - you never know when (even if) the other has read the message - if you need to know, you have to wait for the reply and e.g. check periodically.

- One way would be to block the own thread until the other has stopped, so you can keep your program flow (but cannot do anything else in your main thread).
- Another option would be to implement some kind of event that is fired when a thread is stopped and place the "after the thread has stopped code" there.
- You could also check in certain intervals if the thread has stopped and continue afterwards.
- Some framework classes like `Task` provide a way to execute some code after the task finished, which could be a place for the "after the thread stopped code".
- The `async` / `await` pattern might also help you. Have a look at [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx). I consider this the most advanced approach that's also easy to use once you get used to it.

There are plenty of options, each which different complexity, performance and (dis)advantages. Choose one that best fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks for response. I will try your second and async/await solution (hoping it freeze app for only few milliseconds)